# Gnome3 Setup of Wacom Buttons in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos BT M and am using Ubuntu 19.10. I want to setup the Express Buttons using the Gnome wacom configuration tool. I can already set it to be the CTRL+Z by using

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT M Pad pad" Button 8 key "+ctrl z -ctrl"
```

But I would rather set it up through the gnome settings because there seem to be some compatibility issues with xsetwacom and gnome 3. I'd rather be able to change my settings on the fly without resorting to command line scripts. This button I probably will keep the same throughout all apps so I'm not to worried about changing it later.

The problem is the gnome button assignment routine. It works okay for the first 3 buttons but it captures the keyboard and you have to click a **Done** button. The furthest right button (Button 8) has the **Done** button appearing off the screen so there's no way for me to click it.

Anyone know how to manually edit the gnome config? I see now gconf has been replaced by dconf. I found a description of where to find the keys on this webpage
[Tablet Configuration 3: GNOME 3](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Tablet-Configuration-3%3A-GNOME-3). But I'm having trouble finding the keys I've already assigned. I think I'll need to do something like this?

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.wacom.tablet-button:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/wacom/usb:${VENDOR}-${PRODUCT}/${BUTTONID} action-type`

But i need to put in the correct ${VENDOR} and ${Product}$. I think I know how what the BUTTONID's may be and know how to find the appropriate keys once I fill in this info. Any Idea how to find it? I had bad luck finding the wacom area in dconf-editor?

Here's the output of `xsetwacom --list devices`

```
Wacom Intuos BT M Pad pad           id: 10  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen stylus        id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen eraser        id: 16  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen cursor        id: 17  type: CURSOR
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the GUI in Ubuntu 20.04 -- I cannot configure some of the buttons because the relevant dropdown menu seems to be displayed outside the visible screen area. (Sometimes it jumps around.)

But I think the issue can be solved using the `dconf editor`.  After installing and opening this editor and navigating to `/org/gnome/desktop/periphals/tablets/`, I see my device listed with some cryptic id (`056a:0357`).  Underneath that device, I find a list of buttons (`buttonA`, `buttonB`, etc.)  The values of buttons A & B do show the configuration that I made via the GUI, so I believe the remaining buttons C & D could be configure here.